# Django automatically append hyperlink url to the existing url

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner of django, currently I am having a url problem.

For example, in our `base.html` page, we hard coded some hyper link tag like `<a href="home.html">home</a>` and if we try to navigate to this page from other page for like `localhost:8000/shop_online.html/category/jewelry` and click the hyperlink then we will be redirected to the home page but with the url looks like this: `localhost:8000/shop_online.html/category/jewelry/index.html`.

I think this has something to do with the urls.py and the hard coded hyper link tag, but I am confused and don't know how to solve this, I think is a pretty easy problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add `/` in your `href` attribute:

```
<a href="/home.html">home</a>
```

However, probbably the better solution is to use `url` tag. So it should look like:

```
<a href="{% url index %}">home</a>
```

Here you have a documentation about [url dispatcher in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

And one more thing: you don't need to have this `*.html` extension in your urls.

Comment: Thank you, with the slash, problem solved immediately, I am going to replace the hard coded url into the url tag. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">home</a>
```

It worked for me check the path in urls.py properly.